# Showing Exception while using Sikuli in Webdriver

Tags: sikuli

I have written Sikuli code(in java).showing exception on Pattern(image path).
Just started using selenium webdriver for testing .

**[Code screenshots]**

[image]

Comment: Hover the error and tell us what the compiler is complaining about. What is the error?

Comment: compiler is complaining  that Add argument to match 'Pattern(String, int)'

Comment: In that case the problem is clear. You are required to supply 2 parameters (String and int) while you only supply a String.